# Loading two different content in to two different places by selecting on link without reloading the page. 

Tags: javascript

I am new to web developing and I am looking to use javascript to create a dynamic page that without reloading the page it will change the content of  three different divs (div #1 would be some text with an specific W and H, div #2 would be a picture and dive #3 would be a larger picture)
Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: And where's the new content coming from? Are you able to use a JS library ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)...)

Comment: I am using PHP include to pull the content from a file.

Answer (score 0):

What you simply need to do is attach an event handler some to some event, and then, through javascript, change out the DOM elements for your new view. For example, clicking on a link or button will initiate this change:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      document.getElementById('myElement').attachEvent('click', function()
      {
          var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
          var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
          var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');

          // modify div1, div2, div3 properties, child nodes, etc
      });
 </script>
```

In this situation, I would definitely recommend using jQuery to greatly simplify the amount of code that you will need to write.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure exactly how you were getting the text and image links and if you were using JQuery or not, so this is about as generic as I can put it. You can make it more dynamic by passing the text and image links to the function.

```
function load_divs(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById('IDDIV1');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('IDDIV3');
    var div3 = document.getElementById('IDDIV3');

    div1.style.height = ###px;
    div1.style.width = ###px;
    div1.innerHTML = 'PUT YOUR TEXT HERE';
    div2.innerHTML = '<img src="LINK_TO_IMG" />';
    div3.innerHTML = '<img src="LINK_TO_LARGER_IMG" />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you guy for your help and sorry if I didn't explain my self well here is a link to a diagram of what I am looking to accomplish.   http://www.centerforcare.org/romes/images/SiteDesc.gif